# Xcode 4.3 - error: no identities were available

Tags: xcode4.3

Please, help me.
I would like to put an App in the IOS App Store but always receive this error message (Xcode4.3)

> "No identities are available for signing"
>   Connect to IOS Center, Xcode can obtain identities from the IOS Dev Center...

What do I make wrong??

Answer (score 32):

When you have your project open in Xcode there's a section called Code Signing.  Click the first drop-down menu and you should see a list of identities, you should see at least one iPhone Developer and iPhone Distribution identity.  If you don't an iPhone Distribution identity, or it is under the "identities without Provisioning profiles" subheading, you can resolve this in iOS Dev Center.

Go to iOS Dev Center > iOS Provisioning Portal > Provisioning > Distribution.  You could have an expired profile, if so just modify and re-save it.  If there is no profile then click New Profile.  Then you should see the new iPhone Distribution identity in Xcode which you can now choose.

Answer (score 10):

For me, it was the bundle identifiers that conflicted. Make sure the bundle identifier specified in Xcode > Targets > Info > Bundle Identifier matches the one you registers as App Id in IOS Dev Center > Provisioning Portal > App Ids. Hint can be found in Xcode > Targets > Build Settings > Code Signing, you just need to make the bundle identifiers match.

Comment: Gah! This was my issue. Stupidly had two slightly different strings for these. Fixed the app manually to make the bundle ID match the distribution profile ID and suddenly everything got signed. +1 for you.

Answer (score 9):

I was running into a problem where everything appeared to be fine (none of the certificates were expired), but Xcode was giving me that error message. However, once I downloaded and installed the .mobileprovision file it worked correctly. For some reason the Xcode automatic download wasn't working correctly.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had the same experience - and trying the automatic download after I'd manually downloaded the provisioning profiles then removed them.

Answer (score 1):

i got the same error, when the scheme for archiving was set to "release" instead to "distribution".

Click **"Manage Schemes"** in XCode then **"Edit..."** to verify your settings.

Answer (score 0):

I just renewed my iOS Developer membership. And this problem drove me crazy as I wanted to submit my app.

1. to Developer portal
2. iOS provisioning profiles
3. Select (your) Distribution Profile
4. Edit --> select the correct App ID
5. Generate and download it